# Why foo() output 2 in react-native, but Chrome console output 3?

Tags: javascript, react-native

```
foo(x, y = function() { x = 2; }) {
    var x = 3;
    y();
    console.warn(x);
}

foo();
```

Why foo() output 2 in react-native, but Chrome console output 3?

Comment: The example code lacks function declaration. If simply pasted, this code will produce a syntax error in Chrome, not 3. However, if a declaration is added, the code indeed produces 3 in Chrome. If I were a Javascript engine, I'd also output 3 here :)

Comment: Ideally it should print `3` as `x` in anonymous function will point to argument `x` and not variable `x`.

Comment: In react-native the function should not be written.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

React-Native, by default, compiles code to ES2015 so the code actually runs should be similar to:

```
function foo(x) {
  var y = arguments.length > 1 && arguments[1] || function() {
    x = 2;
  }
  var x = 3;
  y();
  console.warn(x);
}
```

So when you run `y()` the `x` referenced is the `x` declared with `var x = 3;`. In Chrome console that actually supports default arguments, `x` references the variable in the arguments. See the code below:

```
function foo(x, y=function() { console.warn(x); x = 2; }) {
  var x = 3;
  y();
  console.warn(x);
}
```

When you run `foo(5)` you'll see:

```
5
3
```

Comment: Variable `x` will be hoisted. In current code, since `y` is defined before `x`, `x=2` will point to `x` in args. Code might look something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/m8jj8wka/)

Answer (score 1):

The reasion is @Lucas answered. ES2015 can not support default args. react native compiles code to ES2015.

```
foo(x, y=function() { console.warn(z); x = 2; z = 3}) {
  var x = 3;
  y();
  console.warn(x);
}
```

So, foo(5) show "Can't find variable:z".

Chrome can support default args.

```
 function foo(x, y=function() { console.warn(z); x = 2; z = 3 }) {
  var x = 3;
  y();
  console.warn(x);
}
```

foo(5), you'll see:

```
3
3
```